# How to prevent find :submit to enable rest of the buttons in the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, submit

Hello I have form that has an option to enable/disable some fields. If user selects `No` as an option for particular section of the form all fields in that form will be disabled. However, I use this logic when saving form data:

```
frmObject.find(":submit").prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button
```

then this code to enable submit button:

```
frmMessage.show().addClass(obj.CLASS).html("Error!").delay(7000).fadeOut('slow').queue(function(){
    $(this).removeClass(obj.CLASS).dequeue();
    frmObject.find(":submit").prop('disabled', false);  // Enable submit button                                       
});
```

Problem that I have after form is submitted and successfully saved code that enables submit button will affect other buttons in the form that should remain disabled. I'm not sure why since the other buttons have `<button></button>` tag and they do not have `type=submit`. Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure why since the other buttons have  tag
>   and they do not have type=submit. Does anyone know how to prevent this
>   behavior?

The default `type` for `<button>` is `submit`. It's a good idea to always specify the `type` explicitly:

```
<button type="button">I'm NOT a Submit Button</button>
<button>I'm AM a Submit Button</button>
```

Comment: Marcus thanks for pointing that out. I must left that while developing my front end code. That fixed the problem. Default behavior was selecting each button in the form that did not have specified type attribute.